# how to pass argument to mpirun in ctest using cmake's execute_process

Tags: cmake, mpi, ctest

I use cmake to execute custom ctest command as below

Macro.cmake:

```
execute_process(
   COMMAND
   ${MPI_RUN} -np ${NUM_PROC} ${OPTS} ${EXECUTABLE}
   RESULT_VARIABLE status
)
```

In the ctest file, the macro is invoked as:

```
add_test(test1 "cmake" "-DMPI_RUN=mpirun" "-DOPTS=--bind-to none" "-DNUM_PROC=2" "-DEXECUTABLE=executable" "-P" "Macro.cmake")
```

Running ctest with verbose, I can see that the command is constructed as

'mpirun' '-np' '2' '--bind-to none' 'executable'

Because of the single quote, mpirun returns the error with error message:

```
mpirun: Error: unknown option "--bind-to none"
```

Note that the explicit command

```
mpirun -np 2 --bind-to none executable
```

runs fine. So is this the bug of cmake/ctest, or what to do to pass the mpi's arguments correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to list:

```
string(REPLACE " " ";" OPTS ${OPTS})
```